# How can I create global variables if I have a MDIParent?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to develop an application on which I have an `MDIParent` and several `MDIchilds`. I would like to create a global variable on my `MDIParent`, and I want that variable to be accessible from its children.

How can I do that??

Comment: I think will be correct set reference to common data object into MDIChilds constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Matthew Watson's answer isn't what you're after...

If you just want your "global" variable to be accessible to the children of a particular MDI parent form, then just use a regular instance property on it. The children will be able to access it through `child.MdiParent.MyVariable` (after casting `MdiParent` to the appropriate type). For example:

```
class ParentForm
{
    public int MyVariable
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class ChildForm
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var parent = this.MdiParent as ParentForm;
        foo = parent.MyVariable;
    }
}
```

---

A quick note: it's generally best to avoid using "global" variables (i.e. static fields/properties) as much as possible. Keep all the different parts of your program's state confined to the appropriate context to reduce coupling. See the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: @Sonhja See my update for some comments on use of globals variables!

Comment: Thanks, but this is a quick application and I need a global user for it ;) But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A global variable in C# is effectively a static field or property.

So just add a public static property to MDIParent:

```
public static int MyGlobalInt
{
    get
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

That will be shared among ALL instances of MDIParent. If that's not what you meant, then it's not a global you want.